# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Microsoft Office 365 Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

Good day everyone

Currently we have 7 legacy applications that are made in ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET Framework 4.5.1) and we want to use our Microsoft Office 365, I have to experience on using this for the older .Net Framework,can you recommend a tutorial video or post for this? I tried to check on the internet but most of them are for the .NET core to .NET 7.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Not 100% clear on what you are asking. Do you want your application to be able to authenticate itself to be able to access documents that you usually open with Office 365?